# Query using EF "Include" and including the related tables on Where

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

So far, I thought I could do:

```
 var num = db.MyTable.Include(x => x.RelatedTable)
           .Count( x.idTenant == CurrentTenantID && x.Active &&
              x.RelatedTable.SomeProperty.Value == true);
```

This always return zero records.
Am I assuming wrongly that Including the RelatedTable I can use it in the where part?

By the way... the "SomeProperty" is Nullable, that is why the ".Value".

I'm  using Entity Framework 4.1. (Database first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the number of records?  If so, why do you even need the `Include`?  Entity Framework will lazy-load the `RelatedTable` entity set for you when it evaluates your `Count` condition.  Also, if `SomeProperty` is a `bool?`, you should check if it has a value before you check the value itself.

```
var num = db.MyTable.Count(x => 
    x.idTenant == CurrentTenantID && 
    x.Active && 
    (x.RelatedTable.SomeProperty.HasValue && 
     x.RelatedTable.SomeProperty.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the "Include" was mandatory in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `Include` if you only want to access navigation property in `Where` part. `Include` is only used to fetch (eager load) related records together with the main record from database to your application but it doesn't make sense if you only want to count records.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that the "Include" was mandatory in this case.